# How to use a WITH clause in conjuction with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I've got the following query which is not running:

```
with countf as (
    select nationid, count(*) as c from customer
    group by nationid
),
maxf as ( select max(nationid) from customer )

select c.customerid, c.nationid from customer c, countf cf, maxf m
where c.nationid = cf.nationid
and cf.c = m
```

The problem seems to be that `m` is a record instead of an Integer. However, if I run it as a subquery as follows:

```
cf.c = ( select max(nationid) from customer )
```

it works as expected. I presume that I'm using the with statement just not the intended way. Trying

```
cf.c in maxf
```

makes me assume that a table generated using `WITH` is just not supposed to be used in a `WHERE` clause.

I know that there are other ways to get the same query using `all` for example. I'm really only interested how I'm supposed to use the with statement. Can I only use it to `SELECT` from it later on?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: As an aside, that join syntax you are using should have died already. You might find the world is a better place if you use Explicit Join syntax

Comment: @JohnHC noted, thanks for the heads up. I never really use SQL though, I much rather have to write it on paper for exams so I try to keep it as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the condition `and cf.c = m` which should be like below

```
with countf as (
    select nationid, count(*) as c from customer
    group by nationid
),
maxf as ( select max(nationid) as max_nationid from customer )

select c.customerid, c.nationid from customer c, countf cf, maxf m
where c.nationid = cf.nationid
and cf.c = m.max_nationid
```

Sidenote: Use a proper ANSI style `JOIN` syntax which is more readable like

```
select c.customerid, 
c.nationid from customer c
join  countf cf on c.nationid = cf.nationid
join maxf m on cf.c = m.max_nationid
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the quick answer! Would you mind clarifying why this is needed for a table generated with a WITH statement compared to an inline subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use the record syntax:

```
and row(cf.c) = m
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you do that? since `m` here is a cte alias ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I have just tested.